# "git config --global credential.helper cache" not caching under win7+cygwin

Tags: git, windows-7, cygwin

I'm using git on a win7 machine with cygwin installed (git version 1.7.9, not using cygwin bash but with cygwin/bin in the windows PATH variable and using the normal windows command shell) and in order to not have to type my credentials every other git command, I figured I'd use the credential helper,

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

however, after issuing this command and doing a git fetch from my git: repository, which prompts me for my password, any subsequent command that requires credentials still asks me for my password instead of using the cached values through the credential helper.

Would anyone know how to make cygwin's git in windows 7 properly cache credentials? (All questions I could find on SO about this were for msys setups).

Answer (score 0):

This feature uses unix domain socket for communication so it does not work on Windows native Git at all. You can check out this project as a substitution: http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/

**UPD** I thought (for some reason) you are using native Windows Git with cygwin installed alongside. If you are using cygwin's git it's strange that nothing work. I leave an answer here, maybe it'll help somebody.

Comment: indeed, it's cygwin's own git, running in the windows command shell from c:\cygwin\bin\git.exe - it picks up pretty much everything correctly, but this, for some reason, doesn't work at all.

Comment: Did you try to use bash instead of cmd.exe?

Comment: for testing purposes, yes. It has the same result. The config command runs without an error, but the credentials don't get cached

Comment: Does it create a socket (default path is `~/.git-credential-cache/socket`)? And do you have `credential-helper` listen by `git help -a | grep credential`

Comment: And check your process list please. There must be a running daemon there (my process looks like this: `git-credential-cache--daemon /Users/vbo/.git-credential-cache/socket`)

Comment: no `~/.git-credential-cache/socket` file, although the dir itself exists. both `credential-cache` and `credential-cache--daemon` are listed in the help  (git 1.7.9 so they should be, anyway). There is, however, no daemon running in the process list.

Comment: It's a problem. Daemon should start when you enter credentials for the first time. Please try to execute this command: `git credential-cache--daemon ~/.git-credential-cache/test`. It should start the daemon and listen to socket. But maybe there will be some error message instead.

Comment: that pipes "ok" the console, then exits without errors. then issuing the cache instruction and doing a "git fetch origin" asks for a password every time rather than it getting cached. I also do not see a /test file in the credential dir while the daemon runs.

Comment: It does not work as expected. When I issue this command it pipes OK and does not exit immediately. Instead it enters an infinite loop until I send keyboard interrupt. So looks like the bug is here, your daemon crashes for some reason. What about `git credential-cache--daemon /tmp/git_daemon_test`? It should respond with "The permissions on your socket directory are too loose" and exit. I am going to try the whole feature on win7/cygwin in a couple of hours and get back to you.

Comment: yup, that generates the "too loose" error. The regular daemon command will sit waiting for a while, then sets for a while, but exits after 1~2 minutes.

Comment: Just rechecked using win7x64/cygwin. Cache works without issues. Manually running daemon (with the command I've asked you to run) exits after 2 minutes indeed, that is strange but when used through config specification (like in original question) everything works fine. After first successful login daemon starts and visible in `ps aux | grep git`, it creates a socket in `~/.git-credential-cache`. Did you try to use another socket instead of the default one? Directory containing it must be `chmod 700`, recheck this. If nothing helps from my point it looks like there is a bug in your cygwin =(

Comment: And recheck your `.git/config` and `~/.gitconfig`, maybe you'll notice some bugs there.

Comment: I wonder if the OP could solve his problem? I found this page while looking how to setup git credential helper on Cygwin. The `git config --global credential.helper cache` line from the question was everything that was needed for me. Daemon starts, socket is created, everything working... Using x86 cygwin on win7x64 (when I installed cygwin x64 was not advertised as stable yet). Btw is there really any benefit from upgrading to x64 cygwin?